# How to track download content

Tags: google-analytics, download, aem, adobe-analytics

I have a requirement where I need to track the event of mostly downloaded pdfs/zip file from AEM. So for that I was thinking about two ways -

1) Use Adobe analytics and track the download event. After I will write a component in AEM to query Adobe analytic to give the result. But I could not find document on how to query analytics data from Adobe AEM.

2) Use tracker.js. But when I hit this url then this url host:port/libs/wcm/stats/tracker.js?path=/content/dam/geometrixx/documents/GeoCube_Datasheet.pdf then it says "impression added" but there is no way to see impression in console. Where I can see the impression? Is tracker.js only for page tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Google Analytics I would go with an event trigger (or a virtual pageview if you prefer that). see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136922?hl=en-GB

in both cases you will be able to track it (and see it happening in the debug console).

Comment: Thanks Marcel, I'm sorry that I do not have much idea on Google Analytics. Two questions 1) Is it possible to track download event in GA 2) Is it possible to query GA data and fetch required information from our application?

Comment: Hope it is still relevant. 1. yes, see my reply. 2. not sure what you mean.